# ANDROID start service at specific time every day

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service, alarmmanager

After the boot is completed, I want to start a service at a specific time (for example at 3 am) every day, but without repeating, for example, every thirty seconds or minutes, or hour but the alarm must repeat every day at 3 am.

Finally, why the alarm start at 3 am after boot complete and if I restart the device at 3.05 am the alarm wakes up anyway?

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

You should register `BroadcastReceiver`, which will be listening for event, broadcasted when device is loaded. This receiver has to run some service (perhaps `IntentService`), which will figure out what time is now and setup `AlarmManager` for a specific time.
The second couple Receiver/Service will be handling your alarms. Now use Ordinary Service.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html